# tensorflow workers start before the main thread could initialize variables

Tags: multithreading, tensorflow

I am trying to use tf.train.batch to run enqueue images in multiple threads. When the number of threads is 1, the code works fine. But when I set a higher number of threads I receive an error:

```
Failed precondition: Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable
 [[Node: Variable/read = Identity[T=DT_INT32, _class=["loc:@Variable"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Variable)]]
```

The main thread has to run for some time under one second to index the database of folders and put it into tensor.

I tried to use sess.run([some_image]) before running tf.train.bath loop. In that case workers fail in the background first with the same error, and after that I receive my images.

I tried to use time.sleep(), but it does not seem to be possible to delay the workers.

I tried adding a dependency to the batch:

```
g = tf.get_default_graph()
with g.control_dependencies([init_one,init_two]):
    example_batch = tf.train.batch([my_image])
```

where init_one, and init_two are `tf.initialize_all(variables) and tf.initialize_local_variables()`

the most relevant issue I could find is at: https://github.com/openai/universe-starter-agent/issues/44

Is there a way I could ask the synchronize worker threads with the main thread so that they don't race first and die out ?

A similar and easy to reproduce error with variable initialization happens when set up the epoch counter to anything that is not `None` Are there any potential solutions ? I've added the code needed to reproduce the error below:

```
def index_the_database(database_path):
    """indexes av4 database and returns two tensors of filesystem path: ligand files, and protein files"""
    ligand_file_list = []
    receptor_file_list = []
    for ligand_file in glob(os.path.join(database_path, "*_ligand.av4")):
        receptor_file = "/".join(ligand_file.split("/")[:-1]) + "/" + ligand_file.split("/")[-1][:4] + '.av4'
        if os.path.exists(receptor_file):
            ligand_file_list.append(ligand_file)
            receptor_file_list.append(receptor_file)

    index_list = range(len(ligand_file_list))
    return index_list,ligand_file_list, receptor_file_list


index_list,ligand_file_list,receptor_file_list = index_the_database(database_path)

ligand_files = tf.convert_to_tensor(ligand_file_list,dtype=tf.string)
receptor_files = tf.convert_to_tensor(receptor_file_list,dtype=tf.string)

filename_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([ligand_files,receptor_files],num_epochs=10,shuffle=True)

serialized_ligand = tf.read_file(filename_queue[0])
serialized_receptor = tf.read_file(filename_queue[1])

image_one = tf.reduce_sum(tf.exp(tf.decode_raw(serialized_receptor,tf.float32)))

image_batch = tf.train.batch([image_one],100,num_threads=100)


init_two = tf.initialize_all_variables()
init_one = tf.initialize_local_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess,coord=coord)
sess.run([init_one])
sess.run([init_two])

while True:
    print "next"
    sess.run([image_batch])
```

Comment: I have not used the coordinator before, but don't you have to register each thread with it before runing it? with `tf.train.Coordinator.register_thread(thread)`

Comment: @cleros thanks for proposed suggestion. Indeed I found some sort temporary solution in starting a my first batch with a single thread (once) and then running my training loop with multiple threads. I wonder if someone suggests how to do it (sync threads/add dependency) right.